# Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I decided to create a firebase messaging app based off of the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQyrwxMPm88

And so far I can get the ui up, just when I type in a message and hit the enter button it displays:

[image]

And I think it has something to do with one of the fields not returning a value, but I don't know what fields aren't returning a value. Probably something to do with the message idk.

I have put previously:

firestore.settings({ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true });

into there and it doesn't crash when I do that, but then I can't send a message.

Here is my App.Js code (note: I haven't done javascript previously)

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/analytics';

import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { useCollectionData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';

const auth = firebase.auth();
 const firestore = firebase.firestore();
 
 const analytics =firebase.analytics();

function App() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <h1></h1>
        <SignOut />
      </header>

      <section>
        {user ? <ChatRoom /> : <SignIn/>}
      </section>
    </div>
  );

}

function SignIn() {
const signInWithGoogle = () => {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
}

  return (
    <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with Google</button>
  )

}

function SignOut() {
  return auth.currentUser && (

    <button onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Sign Out</button>
  )
}

function ChatRoom() {
  const dummy= useRef();
  const messagesRef = firestore.collection('messages');
  const query = messagesRef.orderBy('createdAt').limit(25);

  const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, {idField: 'id'});
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState(''); 

  const sendMessage = async(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    const {uid,photoURL}= auth.updateCurrentUser;

    await messagesRef.add({
      text: formValue,
      createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      uid,
      photoURL
    });

    setFormValue('');
    dummy.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <main>
 
        {messages&& messages.map(msg => <ChatMessage key={msg.id} />)}
 
      <span ref={dummy}></span>

      </main>
     
      <form onSubmit={sendMessage}>

      <input value={formValue} onChange={(e) => setFormValue(e.target.value)} placeholder="say something nice" />

        <button type="submit" disabled={!formValue}></button>
          
      </form>

    </>
  )
}

function ChatMessage(props) {
  const {text, uid, photoURL}= props.message; 

  const messageClass= uid === auth.currentUser.uid ? 'sent' : 'received';

  return (<>
    <div classname={`messages ${messageClass}`}>
      <img src={photoURL || 'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/23/abott@adorable.png'} />
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
    </>
  )

  
}

export default App;
```

Note I also changed to true for my firestire.rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const {uid,photoURL}= auth.updateCurrentUser;
```

The [`updateCurrentUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#updatecurrentuser) is a method and not a property on the auth instance which *asynchronously sets the provided user as currentUser on the current Auth instance.* Also it returns void.

Are you trying to get UID and photoURL of current user? Use [`currentUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#currentuser) property instead. Also it's better to add a check if user is logged in:

```js
const sendMessage = async(e) =>{
  e.preventDefault();
  const curUser = auth.currentUser
  if (curUser) {
    const {uid, photoURL} = curUser;

    await messagesRef.add({
      text: formValue,
      createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      uid,
      photoURL
    });

    setFormValue('');
    dummy.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  } else {
    console.log("NO user logged in")
  }
}
```